# Rescaling solution in matrix equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf{p}(t)}{ \mathrm{d} t}=(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{A})\mathbf{p}(t)
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{A}$ is a symmetric $N\times N$ matrix and $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix.

The solution is simply:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{p}(t)=e^{(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{A})t}\mathbf{p}(0)
\end{equation}

Now consider the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \mathbf{q}(t)}{ \mathrm{d} t}=(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}^{-1})\mathbf{q}(t)
\end{equation}

**My question:** Can I express $\mathbf{q}(t)$ in terms of $\mathbf{p}(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Unvec#1{\operatorname{Unvec}\BR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$
Assume that a matrix $X$ exists such that
$\,q = Xp.\;$

This ansatz yields
$$\eqalign{
\dot q &= X\dot p \\
 &= X\LR{D-A}p \\
 &= X\LR{D-A}\LR{X^{-1}q} \\
 &= \LR{XFX^{-1}}q \\
}$$
You would like the matrix in parentheses to equal the matrix
$\,G=(I-AD^{-1})$

Therefore
$$\eqalign{
G &= XFX^{-1} \qiq
GX &= XF \\
}$$
which is a [Sylvester Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) which can sometimes be solved for the unknown $X$ matrix.

One approach is to use vectorization
$$\eqalign{
0 &= \BR{I\otimes G - F^T\otimes I}\,\vec{X} \\
0 &= M\,\vec{X} \\
}$$
This means that $\vec{X}$ lies in the nullspace of $M$.

Continuing with an arbitrary vector $y$ and the pseudoinverse $M^+$
$$\eqalign{
\vec{X} &= \LR{I-M^+M}y \\
X &= \Unvec{y-M^+My} \\
}$$
If $\,M^+M=I\,$ then this approach fails, and a solution of the assumed form does not exist.